# how to add legend to matplot?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have already have the matplot using the following codes.

```
P1 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2/3, 1/3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)

run.mc.sim <- function( P, num.iters = 50 ) { 
num.states <- nrow(P)
states     <- numeric(num.iters)
states[1]    <-  1
for(t in 2:num.iters) {   
p  <- P[states[t-1], ]
states[t] <-  which(rmultinom(1, 1, p) == 1)
}
return(states)
}

num.chains     <- 5
num.iterations <- 50

chain.states1  <- matrix(NA, ncol=num.chains, nrow=num.iterations)

for(c in seq_len(num.chains)){
  chain.states1[,c] <- run.mc.sim(P1)
}

matplot(chain.states1, type='l', lty=1, col=1:5, ylim=c(0,4), 
main='Simulation of P1 in 50 steps',ylab='state', xlab='time')
abline(h=1, lty=3)
abline(h=4, lty=3)
```

The only problem is I don't know how to add a legend on the plot corresponding to the colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
legend("topright", legend=LETTERS[1:5], lty=1, col=1:5, inset=c(0,0.1))
```

You will need to replace LETTERS[1:5] with the labels that you actually want.